# Character frequency in a string

Tags: r

I want to create a function with two arguments that will show me frequency of a character in a given word: x <- word, y <- letter. So, I created the following function:

```
frequency <- function(x,y)
{
    word <- strsplit(x,"")
    counter <- 0
    for (i in 1:length(word)){
        if (word[i] == y) counter=counter+1
    }
    print(counter)
}
```

The basic idea of this function was to split characters of a given a word, iterate over them and increase the value of a counter if the condition is met. This function however always returns a value of 0. What's the cause of this?

Comment: Instead of your loop, try `sum(word == y)`. Oh, but the problem you're seeing is because you need to do `strsplit(x,"")[[1]]` or wrap in `unlist`.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why is it necessary to add [[1]]]?

Comment: You need to return a value at the end. `print` prints the value to the screen, but returns the NULL object. Replace ` print(counter)` with `counter` or `return(counter)`.

Comment: Yeah, it's necessary because `strsplit` can take a vector of strings and split them, and the natural way to handle that case is to return a list. Try `strsplit(c("ABC", "defg"))`. To keep the output consistent, it returns a list even when there's only one string. The `[[1]]` extracts the first element of the list.

Answer (score 3):

Another version is to translate your 'word' into a `raw()` vector and compare to the 'letter' as a `raw()` vector.

```
frequency = function(word, letter)
    sum(charToRaw(word) == charToRaw(letter))
```

Here are four different solutions

```
f0 <- function(word, letter)
    sum(strsplit(word, "")[[1]] == letter)

f1 <- function(word, letter)
    sum(charToRaw(word) == charToRaw(letter))

f2a <- function(word, letter)
    length(unlist(gregexpr(letter, word)))

f2b <- function(word, letter)
    length(unlist(gregexpr(letter, word, fixed=TRUE)))
```

with some correctness and performance comparisons

```
> word <- "foo"
> letter <- "o"
> identical(f0(word, letter), f1(word, letter))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(word, letter), f2a(word, letter))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(word, letter), f2b(word, letter))
[1] TRUE
> letter <- "a"
> identical(f0(word, letter), f1(word, letter))
[1] TRUE
> identical(f0(word, letter), f2a(word, letter))
[1] FALSE
> identical(f0(word, letter), f2b(word, letter))
[1] FALSE
> word <- paste(sample(letters, 10000, TRUE), collapse="")
> letter <- "a"
> microbenchmark(
+     f0(word, letter), f1(word, letter),
+     f2a(word, letter), f2b(word, letter)
+ )
Unit: microseconds
              expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
  f0(word, letter) 558.433 562.4755 579.03451 583.5590 584.8920  628.946   100
  f1(word, letter)  71.482  78.7100 100.85787  80.0275  81.7035 2195.366   100
 f2a(word, letter) 277.618 278.7280 280.94280 279.4870 280.4270  302.683   100
 f2b(word, letter)  66.888  68.1800  69.07205  68.6205  69.3100   84.300   100
```

`f2b()` is the fastest but also not correct; `f1()` seems at the moment to be both fast (though maybe speed isn't important for the task at hand) and correct.

Answer (score 1):

As noted by Frank, it is usually better to avoid loops. You can do that easily like so:

```
word <-"Word"
y <-"d"

sum(unlist(strsplit(word,""))==y)
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this without using a `for` loop would be to use the `table` function, which returns a named vector of frequencies. You also need to unlist after using `strsplit`, because it returns a list. Finally, I used the function `tolower` just in case a character string is used with a capital letter (e.g., "Banana" is converted to "banana")

```
freq <- function(x,y) {
  word <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(x,"")))
  word_table <- table(word)
  ans <- word_table[names(word_table)==y]
  return(ans)
}

 freq("mississippi", "s")
```

returns

```
s 
4
```

Note that this only works when a single word is supplied, if instead a string of words is added to `x` then the function would need to be generalized to return the frequency for each word individually.

Answer (score 1):

The logic all looks right. So something is not doing what you think it is.

Check out `word[i]` in your console. It's a list. The first element describes type, the second value. So you're comparing an array to a letter.

```
Browse[2]> word <- strsplit("something",'')
Browse[2]> word[0]
list()
Browse[2]> word[1]
[[1]]
[1] "s" "o" "m" "e" "t" "h" "i" "n" "g"
```

Now in R (Matlab, other data languages) it's kind of discouraged to use loops. Rather you should be using R functions to look through lists. Check out the function [table](https://www.r-bloggers.com/r-function-of-the-day-table/) - it uses a functional approach in which you send the comparison to the function:

```
frequency <- function(x,y)
{
  word <- strsplit(x,'')
  val <- table(word[1] == y)["TRUE"]
  cat(val)
}
frequency("hih","h")
```

Then

```
Browse[2]> frequency("hih","h")
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is something that you need to do with the strsplit(). If not:

```
x <- "c"
y <- "confluence is crazy cc"
count_string <- function(x,y){
  count <- if(unlist(gregexpr(x,y))[1] == -1) 0 else length(unlist(gregexpr(x,y))) 
  return(count)
  }
> count_string(x,y)
[1] 5
> count_string("xx",y)
[1] 0
```

gregexpr() returns the position location for each match it finds in a list. It returns -1 if no match is found. We count the list to return the number of times it matched in your string.

Comment: This returns the wrong answer when there are no matches, e.g., `count_string("foo", "b")`

Comment: Ack. Thanks @MartinMorgan Let me see about fixing that.

Answer (score 0):

```
mf <- function(x, y){
  count <- table(strsplit(x, '')[[1]])
  count[names(count) == y]
}

mf('hello world', 'l')
# l
# 3
```