# Composite score function fails on data frame but works on single set of values

Tags: r

I created a function to calculate a numeric score, based on three strings containing characters A thru F.  The intermediate scores are calculated by determining the most frequent character for each string.  The final score is calculated by majority voting.  If all three intermediate scores are different, then the final numeric score is the mean of all intermediate scores.  I know that the function is not optimized - there are several ways in which I could write it better.  Any suggestions are more than welcome!

I got part of the code from the following StackOverflow issue...
[Character frequency in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43412880/character-frequency-in-a-string)

```
fncLetterValue <- function(strLetter)
{
  intValue = 9
  if(strLetter=="A") intValue <- 1
  if(strLetter=="B") intValue <- 2
  if(strLetter=="C") intValue <- 3
  if(strLetter=="D") intValue <- 4
  if(strLetter=="E") intValue <- 5
  if(strLetter=="F") intValue <- 6
  return(intValue)
}

fncScore <- function(str1, str2, str3)
{
  # determine frequency of letters in str1
  A1 <- sum(charToRaw(str1)==charToRaw("A"))
  B1 <- sum(charToRaw(str1)==charToRaw("B"))
  C1 <- sum(charToRaw(str1)==charToRaw("C"))
  D1 <- sum(charToRaw(str1)==charToRaw("D"))
  E1 <- sum(charToRaw(str1)==charToRaw("E"))
  F1 <- sum(charToRaw(str1)==charToRaw("F"))
  Max1 <- max(A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1) # determine the maximum frequency
  Score1 <- 9
  if(A1==Max1) Score1 <- 1
  if(B1==Max1) Score1 <- 2
  if(C1==Max1) Score1 <- 3
  if(D1==Max1) Score1 <- 4
  if(E1==Max1) Score1 <- 5
  if(F1==Max1) Score1 <- 6

  # determine frequency of letters in str2
  A2 <- sum(charToRaw(str2)==charToRaw("A"))
  B2 <- sum(charToRaw(str2)==charToRaw("B"))
  C2 <- sum(charToRaw(str2)==charToRaw("C"))
  D2 <- sum(charToRaw(str2)==charToRaw("D"))
  E2 <- sum(charToRaw(str2)==charToRaw("E"))
  F2 <- sum(charToRaw(str2)==charToRaw("F"))
  Max2 <- max(A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2) # determine the maximum frequency
  Score2 <- 9
  if(A2==Max2) Score2 <- 1
  if(B2==Max2) Score2 <- 2
  if(C2==Max2) Score2 <- 3
  if(D2==Max2) Score2 <- 4
  if(E2==Max2) Score2 <- 5
  if(F2==Max2) Score2 <- 6

  # determine frequency of letters in str3
  A3 <- sum(charToRaw(str3)==charToRaw("A"))
  B3 <- sum(charToRaw(str3)==charToRaw("B"))
  C3 <- sum(charToRaw(str3)==charToRaw("C"))
  D3 <- sum(charToRaw(str3)==charToRaw("D"))
  E3 <- sum(charToRaw(str3)==charToRaw("E"))
  F3 <- sum(charToRaw(str3)==charToRaw("F"))
  Max3 <- max(A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3) # determine the maximum frequency
  Score3 <- 9
  if(A3==Max3) Score3 <- 1
  if(B3==Max3) Score3 <- 2
  if(C3==Max3) Score3 <- 3
  if(D3==Max3) Score3 <- 4
  if(E3==Max3) Score3 <- 5
  if(F3==Max3) Score3 <- 6

  # get final score by majority voting
  dblFinalScore <- 9
  if(Score1==Score2 | Score1==Score3) dblFinalScore <- Score1
  if(Score2==Score1 | Score2==Score3) dblFinalScore <- Score2
  if(Score3==Score1 | Score3==Score2) dblFinalScore <- Score3
  if(dblFinalScore==9) dblFinalScore <- mean(c(Score1,Score2,Score3))

  return(dblFinalScore)
}

# read csv
setwd("~/Downloads")
df <- read.csv("CompositeScore.csv", header = TRUE)

df$score <- fncScore(df$Vector1, df$Vector2, df$Vector3) #THIS LINE GIVES AN ERROR!
```

The function does work in the console for one set of strings...
e.g. fncScore("AAAABBBBBBBBB","ABBCCCCCCCCCC","FFFFFFFFFFF")

[1] 3.666667

However, the same function does not work for a dataframe.
I get the following error:
"Error in charToRaw(str1) : argument must be a character vector of length 1"

I expected to get a new column in the dataframe with the final scores.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Here is the sample CSV file ...   https://drive.google.com/open?id=1aNZkBaUO752Q9WJEPms0WDTtft0RFnJG

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood your scoring system correctly, I think this does what you are looking for using the `tidyverse`...

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("CompositeScore.csv")

scores <- function(x){   #function to identify most common letter in each string
  map_int(x, ~which.max(str_count(., LETTERS[1:6])))
}

df <- df %>% 
  gather(key = Vector, value = value, -Observation) %>%  #change to 'long' format
  mutate(score = scores(value)) %>%                      #calculate scores
  group_by(Observation) %>%                              #group by Observation for next line
  mutate(score = ifelse(sum(score == median(score)) > 1, #if two the same
                        median(score),                   #then median
                        mean(score))) %>%                #otherwise mean
  spread(key = Vector, value = value)                    #back to wide format

head(df)

  Observation score Vector1      Vector2      Vector3     
1           1  3.33 CCEDDBEACBAD ADAABEEAEADD ACEFBAFDFDCB
2           2  3.33 ECBDEFACDAEA AFDEECDBEDFF EBEFCCEAEDFB
3           3  5    BDDDBBAFDFFF BBEEDEDBDCAE FFBADEEFCFFF
4           4  4    FDDFDEFBCBBA FECEEFDDCDAF FDFCDFEFBBCE
5           5  2    DBBEEDCBEECB CBFCAAFEBBCD FCFFBEBEEBDA
6           6  6    CBAEEEDBEBDF DCABCEAEDFFF CEFFFDBCADFC
```